# php count variable outside loop being reset

Tags: php

I've set `$count` as counter outside `foreach` loop, but it seemed to be reset everytime. This php is used to upload multiple files.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($_FILES["my_file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $count++;
        echo "<script>alert(".$count.");</script>";
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = basename($_FILES["my_file"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/". $SN."/".$name .$count);
        echo json_encode(array('id' => 'message', 'data' => 'successful'));

    }
}
```

`echo "<script>alert(".$count.");</script>";` to observe the counter , and if upload three files it will alert '1' three times. Also, I added `$count` to upload filename, for example , filename `1.jpg,2.jpg` , after uploading ,the filename will become `1.jpg1, 2.jpg1`, it supposed to be `1.jpg1,2.jpg2`. what is wrong with my loop?

html code:

```
<form method="post" action="ImagesUpload.php" id="myForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input name="my_file[]" id="file-fr" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" multiple>           
</form>
```

Comment: Every time you execute the script it will start from the beginning ($count =0) and stops at the end of the file, so $count will only be current at the end of the script.

Comment: I've update html code. It suppose to run one time after submit post, I don't understand why it will run repeatly.

Comment: You should iterate over like that `foreach($_FILES["my_file"] as $key => $file)`.

Comment: i check f12 and found it will post three times if i upload three files, no wonder it will be reset , it there anyway to let it post one time when multiple files upload?

Comment: "it will post three times if i upload three file"...that shouldn't be happening based on the code you've posted...but then again your form has no obvious way for it to be submitted. Are you using Javascript/AJAX to submit the form, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AJAX to upload?
I added a submit button to your code and it worked.

Also, are you sure you are selecting more than one file?

See modified code: 
HTML

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" id="myForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input name="my_file[]" id="file-fr" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text" multiple>   
<input type="submit" >        
</form>
```

PHP

```
$count = 0;
if(isset($_FILES["my_file"])){
    print_r($_FILES["my_file"]);
foreach ($_FILES["my_file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $count++;
        echo "<script>alert(".$count.");</script>";
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = basename($_FILES["my_file"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "upload/". $SN."/".$name .$count);
        echo json_encode(array('id' => 'message', 'data' => 'successful'));

    }
}
}
```

Both blocks of code are in the same file.